# iphone uitableview to another view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, animation, detailsview

in my program I need a tableview and, when you click onto a row, the view scroll left and show the details (like the mail for example...)
how can I do this??
I explain... it's an automatic thing or I need to manage by hand the animation of the view??
thanks in advance

Comment: I think it's way too basic question to ask in the forums. I'd suggest you to try some tutorial first. There are plenty of code samples and tutorials on the web that do exactly what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use UINavigationControllers to achieve this effect of the detail animating left when you click on the row. So you need a UINavigation controller above the UIViewController or UITableView Controller that controls your table.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
    ...my code

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

}

Comment: thanks robert but now I have my UIViewController class that shows the rows, so I need to add where the UINavigation?
thanks

Comment: You create a UINavigationController in your app delegate and then add your UIViewcontroller to it. See the Navbar example in the other guy's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your case is exactly what `UINavigationController` class is for - it will handle your controllers hierarchy and will do animated transition for you as well. To learn how to use it you can have a look at Apple's [NavBar](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html) sample.